# Android: My text is being displayed vertically in a programmatically set TextView

Tags: android, text, textview

I'm adding a TextView to a parent LinearLayout RelativeLayout programmtically. There is enough space for the text to be displayed horizontally but for some reason the text is displayed vertically.  Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: can you present us some code ?

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to say what is the problem without looking at your XML and layout code. In my experience, sometimes it happens when the parent layout has height set as WRAP_CONTENT and the views inside it have wrong weight config, for example one has weight but WRAP_CONTENT and the other MATCH_PARENT (Sorry, I don't remember the case exactly). I suggest you check your LayoutParams carefully or set a fixed width and height for the TextView to see what is the problem.

You can also post your code here so we can have a look at it